# The matrix of the double differentiation operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_n (F)$ be the vector space of all polynomials of degree $\le n$ with coefficients in $F$. Let $S : P_3 (F) \to P_2 (F)$ be diferentiation twice. I am looking for the matrix of $S$ with respect to the bases $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ and $\{1,x,x^2\}$ of $P_3 (F)$ and $P_2 (F)$, respectively.

Since

$1' = 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 \\
x' = 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 \\
(x^2)' = 0 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 \\
(x^3)' = 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 3 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 ,$

the matrix of the derivative operator is $\left( \begin{array} {cccc} 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 2 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 3 && 0 \end{array} \right)$.

Now doing this again,

$0' = 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 \\
1' = 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 \\
(2x)' = 2 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 \\
(3x^2)' = 0 \cdot 1 + 6 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 ,$

and the corresponding matrix is $\left( \begin{array} {cccc} 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 2 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 6 && 0 && 0 \end{array} \right)$.

Now the solution is actually $\left( \begin{array} {ccc} 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 2 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 6 && 0 \end{array} \right) ,$

which is a $4 \times 3$ matrix, but when I multiply the matrices that I have obtained I get a $4 \times 4$ one, so where have I gone wrong?

Comment: If it's $P_3 \to P_3$, then it would be a $4\times 4$ matrix. You do not need that $0x^3$ at all, as $x^3$ is not in $P_2$. The basis for $P_2$ is $\{1, x, x^2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you express the result of differentiation as a combination of $1, x, x^2, x^3$, which means that you consider differentiation as an operator from $P_3$ to $P_3$, so the composition of differentiation with itself will again take values in $P_3$, not in $P_2$. This is fine in principle, but not what the problem asks for. If you really want to express double differentiation as the product of two 1st order derivative operators, consider the second such operator as taking values in $P_2$, not $P_3$, i.e. express its values only as combinations of $1, x, x^2$ (dropping the $x^3$ part). For instance, $(3x^2)' = 0 \cdot 1 + 6 \cdot x + 0  \cdot x^2$ (and similarly for the other monomials).

Still, it is much better to derive twice from the very beginning:

$S(1) = 0 = 0  \cdot 1 + 0  \cdot x + 0  \cdot x^2 \\
S(x) = 0 = 0  \cdot 1 + 0  \cdot x + 0  \cdot x^2 \\
S(x^2) = 2 = 2  \cdot 1 + 0  \cdot x + 0  \cdot x^2 \\
S(x^3) = 6x = 0  \cdot 1 + 6  \cdot x + 0  \cdot x^2 ,$

which is significantly faster, shorter and clearer, and makes the matrix of $S$ easy to read out directly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(e_0,e_1,\ldots, e_n)$ with $e_k:\>x\mapsto x^k$ be the given basis vectors of of $P_n$. Denoting differentiation by $D$ we have
$$De_k=k e_{k-1},\qquad Se_k=D^2 e_k=k(k-1) e_{k-2}\qquad(k\geq0)\ ,$$
where $e_{-1}=e_{-2}:=0$, of course. This says that $$Se_0=Se_1=0,\quad Se_2=2e_0,\quad Se_3=6e_1\ .$$

As ${\rm dim}(P_3)=4$ and ${\rm dim}(P_2)=3$ the requested matrix of $S$ is of type $3\times 4$. The governing rule for setting up this matrix is the following: **In the columns of $[S]$ are the images of the basis vectors.** This at once gives
$$[S]=\left[\matrix{0 &0& 2& 0 \cr
0&0&0&6\cr 0&0&0&0\cr}
\right]\ .$$